# Is there a way to implement "profiles" into an Alexa Skill?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building a nutrition skill and I want to include some calculators. I could have Alexa ask for the parameters each time something is calculated, but I'd prefer to have users set up a basic profile for themselves to store age, height, and weight values.

I found a small section of Amazon's documentation that talks about how the userId element could be used to store attributes across sessions. Will that work for what I'm talking about though? Or will I have to add OAuth?

Comment: `userId` is a unique but opaque identifier for a user.  Using your own database, you can store whatever the user provdes to you, and reference it during future events, even though you don't know who the user is. You can't correlate this to anything external, such as matching this user to a user of your web site, so whether this does what you need depends on your grand scheme.  There's not really enough detail in the question to give a good answer.  Can yoi elaborate?

Comment: Of course, thanks for the reply. I have no website or app to go along with this skill, so I'm thinking of something completely self-contained. I would ask Alexa something like "how much protein should I eat in a day?"; then, she'll ask my age, height, and weight (and maybe a couple other parameters). "Oh, based on this, you should get about 100g of protein a day." I want to then store the parameters for future calculations. So next, the user could just say "what about carbohydrates?" and Alexa gives the response without asking about the user all over again. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes.  Persistence with DynamoDB is easily implemented... official example: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to do this:

1) You can use sessions.

In this method, your data will be vanish when session is end (user stop talking with your skill)
more details https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#session-object

2) You should implement an oauth 2.0 server to store user data. It is not that easy but you can find some oauth server example in here https://oauth.net/code/

For connecting your skill to your oauth server, you can follow here
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/linking-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system

bonus: If you do not want to implement an oauth server, you can use Login with Amazon (or login with google) services. But you will still need a database server to store data

Comment: by the way, heroku.com is a great server for you to store your data or oauth server

Answer (score 0):

The `userId` that you get on your requests uniquely identifies an Amazon account, not a person. Despite the option to switch between different accounts on a single device (see: https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201628040), the feature to identify people has been discussed (http://time.com/4683981/amazon-echo-voice-id-feature-2017/) but it's not available yet.

As already mentioned in the comments, you will need to persist the session information between sessions and you could use the `userId` to identify each account.

But in any case, you don't need account linking or using Oauth to simply identify a person.

Additionally, I'd recommend you to stay within the Amazon ecosystem and run your stuff in Lambda (with free tier and with development credits for developers publishing Alexa skills).

If you need help getting started, I have a single-file template for Alexa skills using Python and several examples:
https://github.com/josepvalls/ask.py